# Are Django cron jobs processes or threads?

Tags: python, django

We are using django-cron version 0.5.1.

Are these cron jobs run as separate process or are these executed as threads inside the main django process ?

Comment: django-cron only sets up the system crontab so the cron jobs work as any other system cronjobs

Answer (score 1):

Since django-cron jobs are run with a management command like so: `python manage.py runcrons` they will run in a separate process than your web app.